# QGIS: Saga Channel network: how to prepare SRTM data

Tags: qgis, saga, hydrology, catchment-area, stream-order

I am trying to use the Saga toolbox (2.2.3) in QGIS (2.18) to create a channel network from SRTM data using this tutorial [1](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/de/docs/training_manual/processing/hydro.html).

It works, but the result I get when using the DEM that comes with the tutorial are much better than what I get when using SRTM DEMs. The channels are mostly not connected to each other, no matter what I try. Is there a way to fix this, or is it because of the SRTM data being not good enough for this analysis?

So far, I am using the following workflow:

1. Catchment area (recursive): Step: 1, Method: Deterministic, Convergence: 1,100000

2: Channel network: Initiation theshold: Greater than 100000. I have also tried Less than 100000 and other values, but that does not help.

Do I need to prepare the SRTM data first before this analysis works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try running **Fill Sinks**. This is available using SAGA via Processing. There may be GRASS versions too. I didn't see any mention of it in the tutorial you linked to, so it's worth a look.

What this does is make tiny adjustments to each cell's height, so that it maintains a minimum downward slope to its neighbours. That way, when you run the algorithms, the virtual water can always find a long uninterrupted path, without getting "trapped" in depressions/pits (these are cells surrounded on all sides by higher neighbours). By the sounds of it, these 'breaks' you see are probably due to these pits.

[This tutorial](http://gracilis.carleton.ca/CUOSGwiki/index.php/Exploring_Hydrological_Analyses_using_SAGA_GIS) explains things well (it assumes you're using SAGA from the saga_gui, but you can do these equally well using Processing).

I'd suggest looking at the SAGA [Fill Sinks (Wang & Liu)](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.3/ta_preprocessor_4.html).

If this is SRTM data, you might also need to check to make sure there are no voids (nodata areas) as these could also need correcting. (To find these I usually set the canvas background to a garish colour like cyan.. if the DEMs are greyscale, voids will stick out like a sore thumb)

Comment: Thanks! I had to adjust the default value of 0,01 to 30. Now it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

You may able to skip the Fill Sinks step by downloading a corrected DEM, recently made available at http://hydro.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yamadai/MERIT_DEM/index.html.
It is a 90 m DEM based on SRTM data and was used to create Hydro rasters, also available to download [here](http://hydro.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~yamadai/MERIT_Hydro/index.html).

These data seem to be high-quality. I'm trying to get a stream network out of them, but am not sure of the easiest way to do this.