# Preparing SRTM (hgt) for use in SAGA GIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, hydrology, srtm

I am trying to prepare a raster file which i could use with SAGA processing tools for hydrologic analysis in QGIS. I am using Win 7, 32 bit, QGIS 2.14.20 and SAGA 2.3.2
I downloaded the srtm file in hgt format from the net. After i converted the file to a Geotiff while reducing the size with the QGIS clipper tool. I changed as well the CRS to UTM.

I have seen on this answer to a rather similiar question: [QGIS: Saga Channel network: how to prepare SRTM data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247936/qgis-saga-channel-network-how-to-prepare-srtm-data) 
that i should try the Fill sinks under SAGA. But even this function doesn´t work with my raster. I get the output, just as for the other tools, that: the layer(s) couldn´t be created.
I am quite sure that my QGIS/ SAGA setup is fine, because i tried all operations with a Raster DEM provided from QGIS and the SAGA tools worked all right and prepared what i am looking for. Therefore i suppose there must be a mistake in my raster file. I tried to change pixel value <=0 to no data value with the raster calulator but without success!  I would be very glad if someone can provide a direction for a solution.

As decribed above i start with the SRTM hgt file.
Step 1: Save the hgt as a Geotiff and change of CRS to UTM with the right click menu under "save as"

Step 2: I created a polygon vector mask layer and used the QGIS clipper under Raster - Extraction - Clipper:

The raster file i get has the following metadata:
]

Step 4: I tried using this layer with different hydrologic processing tools, SAGA and GRASS under QGIS. Here an example for GRASS using the `_r.stream.extract_` tool:

This is the error i will get for unfortunately all the tools i tried to use:

Comment: Give a try to GRASS GIS. See http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/Hydrological_Sciences for options and why sink filling is not needed in GRASS GIS

Comment: Thanks. I am sure that GRASS is a good option. I tried the GRASS 7 in the QGIS processing toolbox. I tried _r.stream.extract_  and _r.watershed_ but i get the same error: _The following layers were not correctly created_ Since i tried again with the raster data provided from QGIS and it worked i am quite sure it must be any problem with my raster file.

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide more info about your data, the commands you tried and the errors. I have used `r.watershed` and `r.water.outlet` many times and it should be a straightforward task

Comment: From the look of the colorful part (assuming it is the clipped area), which has jagged edges, I am afraid you might have reprojected it to UTM after clipper operation. Can you expound the order of your workflow?

Comment: Many thanks. Hope the above amendments clarify the situation.

Comment: I would suggest you to run `r.watershed` on your original htg file with some high value in the "Maximum size of the exterior watershed basin"(100?) and a regional extent based on your mask or just a window.

Comment: I opened an new QGIS project and tried again with `r.watershed` and the file as created above, and following the error indication in the LOG that: `ERROR: The basin threshold must be a positive number.` I changed `Minimum size of exterior water shed basin` and `Maximum length of surface flow, for USLE` from 0 to 1. And it finally worked with GRASS!

Comment: Great! it deserves that you answer yourself